# remove a column of input file in c and write to output file

Tags: c, file

I have a question and I wanted to remove first column from my input file and write it to the output file. I have no idea how to do it. 
I searched through the site but I could not find my intended answer. 
Here is my input file with the first line being header :

```
7 11 11
4 5 1 3 2 2 1
2 1 1 3 2 4 1 
5 5 3 4 2 2 2 1 2
3 2 1 3 2 6 2 7 5 
1 1 1 3 3 6 2
6 5 2 4 2 7 6
2 6 6 4 5
```

and my intended output file will look like this :

```
7 11 11
5 1 3 2 2 1
1 1 3 2 4 1 
5 3 4 2 2 2 1 2
2 1 3 2 6 2 7 5 
1 1 3 3 6 2
5 2 4 2 7 6
6 6 4 5
```

How can I do this in C? 
this is what I have tried so far

```
int main()
{
FILE *ifp;
FILE *ofp;
char fname[]="input.txt";
char fname2[]="input-v2.txt";
char *mode = "r";
int n;
int m;
int fmt;
ifp = fopen(fname, "r");
ofp= fopen(fname2, "w");
char *token;
char *s=" ";
char line[100000];
if (ifp == NULL)
{
   printf("\nFailed to open file.\n");
    exit(1);
}
fscanf(ifp,"%d %d %d",&n,&m,&fmt);
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), ifp)) {
    char *copy=strdup(line);
    if(line[0] == '\n')
        continue;
    char *copy=strdup(line);
    if(line[0] == '\n')
        continue;

    token=strtok(copy,s);

    while (token!=NULL && token!=""){
    char *val=token;
    val="";
    fprintf(ofp,"%s",val)
        token=strtok(NULL,s);
    }
      fprintf(ofp, "\n");
}

fclose(ifp);
return 0;
}
```

I am really not sure what to do. I actually need to remove first character from every line but this unfixed column number make me confused.

Comment: Are no. of columns constant for every line ?

Comment: no it is not. I do not have fixed number of columns in lines

Comment: Could you show what you have tried ? But the idea behind is just to read the file and them remove the 2 first caracters. Btw, what happen with an empty line ?

Comment: What are you having a problem with? The file IO (opening, closing, reading writing)? Or the string manipulation?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I have problem with the process of removing the column.

Comment: @kaldoran I editted my answer so that you can see what I did before. I do not have problem with the empty lines.

Comment: You say as much in your question. But we need specifics! What exactly is it that is not working? You say "unfixed column number" but have not explained what that is... Remember this is not a site where people will just hand you a working program.

Comment: @Toby I cannot configure how to do this using strtok which I used in my program.

Comment: I would use [`strchr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strrchr/) instead. Just read the line, find the first space, then write the rest of the line. `char *space = strchr(line, ' '); if (NULL != space) fprintf(ofp, "%s\n", space + 1);`

Comment: Posted the wrong link in my comment. Here's the right link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of your loop you could use this -

```
token=strtok(copy,s);
token=strtok(NULL,s);              // get complete string after space 
if(token != NULL){
     fprintf(opf, "%s", token); 
}
```

Some problem in your loop -

```
while (token!=NULL && token!=""){
    char *val=token;
    val="";                         // why point val to "" ?
    fprintf(ofp,"%s",&val)          // & is not required with val
    token=strtok(NULL,s);
}
```

Comment: I wanted val to make my token="" which seems not a good logic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I could figure it out by this trick.

Answer (score 1):

I found it by you helps thank you. Here is the solution :

```
 while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), ifp)) {
    char *copy=strdup(line);
    if(line[0] == '\n')
        continue;

    token=strtok(copy,s);
    token=strtok(NULL,s);
    while (token!=NULL && token!=""){
        fprintf(ofp,"%s ",token);
        token=strtok(NULL,s);
     }
    fprintf(ofp, "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which part you are having problems with (indeed you don't show any code you have so far at all...)

Assuming you do not know the logic required to perform the task you describe I have described it in psuedo-code below

```
Open(input-file)
if(open failed)
    Return

Open(output-file)
if(open failed)
{
     Close(input-file)
     Return
}

read(first input-file line) // Get the header line but do nothing with it

while(not end of input-file)
{
    string = read(next input-file line)
    if(line not empty && not just new-line)
    {
        find(first character after first space in string)
        write(remainder of string to output file)
    }
}    

Close(output-file)
Close(input-file)
```

Your example data shows that the first, header, line is not affected by the removal of the column so the first line is read in but then not used (as marked by the inline comment), you could instead simply *seek* the end of the first line and then start the `while` loop after that.